# python loop for calling API

Tags: python, loops

I need to get Geo data for a bunch of IPs (eventually I will need data for 3k+ IPs). I was able to successfully get Geo data for individual IPs. Now I'm truing to create a loop which iterates through IPs stored as separate lines in a text file and then calls ipstack API for getting Geo data. But the code returns data only for last IP in the file with 'missing_access_key' error for the other ones.  I'm a python beginner - so any help would be appreciated.

```
fh = open('IPs.txt')

for line in fh:
    ip = line
    api = 'http://api.ipstack.com/' + ip + '?access_key=' + access_key
    result = urllib.request.urlopen(api).read()
    result = result.decode()
    result = json.loads(result)

    print (result)
```

Comment: It seems your `access_key` is wrong based on [this](https://ipstack.com/documentation)

Comment: I created an account with ipstack and obtained a valid access key. It works when making an API call for individual IP. When I do iteration through a text file it returns data only for last IP in the file with the 'missing_access_key' error for other 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
fh = open('IPs.txt,'r')
Lines = fh.readlines()

for line in Lines:
    ip = line
    api = 'http://api.ipstack.com/' + ip + '?access_key=' + access_key
  result = urllib.request.urlopen(api).read()
  result = result.decode()
  result = json.loads(result)

   print (result)
```

Comment: If txt file only contains IP s

Comment: After making suggested adjustments it still returns the same result - valid data for last IP in the file and 'missing_access_key' error for other 4.

Comment: from where you are getting the access key

Comment: I assigned access key I got from ipstack to a variable earlier in the code